# Include parent attributes when searching via query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, sqlite

I have a User Model that has_many Job Applications.

Everything works great, but when I try to search Job Applications by the User's first_name I get the error below.

**Error**

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: first_name: SELECT  "job_applications"
```

From my understanding, I need to include the User attributes in the Job Application query.

**How can I accomplish this?**

**View** (job application)

```
<%= form_for :search, :html => {:method => :get, :id => 'search'} do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :terms, params[:terms], :type => 'search' %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller** (job application)

```
def index
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @job_applications = @job.job_applications.search(params[:terms])
end
```

**Model** (job application)

```
def self.search(terms)
  terms ||= ""
  conditions = terms.split(" ").map do |term|
    term = term.strip.gsub("'","''")

    ### I am having an issue here...
    ### how do i include the user attributes in this query
    "first_name like '%#{term}%'"
  end
  where(conditions.join " OR ")
end
```

Comment: MySQL or SQLite3 ? Both are different RDBMS. Please fix the tags to include relevant RDBMS only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join `job_applications` table with `users` table.

```
# job_applications.rb

def self.search(terms)
    terms ||= ""
    conditions = terms.split(" ").map do |term|
      term = term.strip.gsub("'","''")
      "users.first_name like :term"
    end
    joins(:user).where(conditions.join " OR ")
end
```

Avoid passing raw user's inputs into your queries directly to avoid sql injection. Use rails' built-in filters or sanitize it yourself.

```
def self.search(terms)
    terms ||= ""
    term_args = []
    conditions = terms.split(" ").map do |term|
      term = term.strip.gsub("'","''")
      term_args << "%#{term}%"
      "users.first_name like ?"
    end
    joins(:user).where(conditions.join(' OR '), term_args)
end
```